# How do open a HTML file as text on OS X?

Tags: macos, html, textedit

How do we open a HTML file on OS X?

I tried open with TextEdit.app but it shows me the HTML page not that HTML source! Even when I put it as "text only" it doesn't work (it just takes the HTML page and strip off everything but the text, which apparently isn't the source code that i would like to view)

Btw I do not wish to download anything extra just to view the source of a HTML page.

Note, I do know that I can open the file in a web browser, select *view source*, then *select all*, *copy*, then open TextEdit.app, then *paste*. That's way too much work.

Comment: What does this have to do with your specific hardware?

Comment: @Daniel I just changed that :)

Comment: @slhck I know, you blocked my edit ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you're opening the file in TextEdit (with the File -> Open dialogue) check the "Ignore rich text commands" checkbox. You can make this the default in the "Open and Save" tab of TextEdit's preferences (the very first checkbox "Ignore rich text commands in HTML files") so it'll work if you just drag a file onto the icon or control-click and do "Open With".

Comment: heys how do i "make this the default in the "Open and Save" tab of TextEdit's preferences (the very first checkbox "Ignore rich text commands in HTML files")". Where is the textedit's preferences?

Comment: "Preferences..." under the "TextEdit" menu - for future reference that's where most Mac applications will keep their preferences.

Comment: +1 So there's actually more to TextEdit than an `NSTextView`. Good to know.

Comment: Note that in addition to checking the "Ignore rich text commands" checkbox from Scott's answer, you may also need to go to the "Open and Save" part of Preferences and select the "Display HTML files as HTML code instead of formatted text" checkbox.

Answer (score 1):

Consider renaming the file to .txt so it opens as plain text.

---

You can always use the Terminal to view or edit the file, e.g. using cat or vim.

Comment: use `less` instead, `cat` just spits *everything* out on your terminal, even escape sequences which can wreck its display.